# Lista horizontal responsiva que se ajusta a 100% de largura da div pai

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Criei uma lista com alguns botões de redes sociais, só que o ultimo botão é do whatsapp, e eu não quero que ele apareça na versão *desktop*, só na *mobile*.

Então eu criei esta media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .socialshare-list-item .socialshare-whatsapp-button {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .socialshare-list-item .socialshare-whatsapp-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

mas quando faço o botão **whatsapp** desaparecer, as outras `<li>` não se ajustam à largura da `div pai` e ficam com um tamanho fixo.

Ela fica assim como no exemplo desta imagem abaixo, e nao ajusta ate à linha final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se possível, faça a postagem do código no jsfiddle.net para que possamos visualizar como está o posicionamento das LI.

Answer (score 2):

Bom pelo que percebi da pergunta, o que estás a tentar fazer aqui é criar **botões de compartilha** para as redes sociais mencionadas na pergunta, e que estes se ajustem a `100%` do tamanho total da `div pai` de maneira a ocupar por completo a mesma.

Se for isso, podes fazê-lo da seguinte maneira: **http://jsfiddle.net/Lhuh8jxx/**
(Aumenta ou diminui a janela do resultado no jsFiddle para veres o código em ação)

```
<ul id="linksPartilha">
    <li class="redeSocial facebookShare"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class="redeSocial twitterShare"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="redeSocial pinterestShare"><a href="#">Pinterest</a></li>
    <li class="redeSocial whatsAppShare whatsApp"><a href="#">WhatsApp</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
#linksPartilha {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;              /* Transforma a div numa tabela */
    table-layout: fixed;         /* Utiliza o algoritmo de uma table fixed */
    border-collapse: separate;   /* Colapsa a tabela para poder adicionar o espaçamento */
    border-spacing: 5px 0px;     /* Adiciona o espaçamento */
}

/* Cria uma lista horizontal com espaçamento */
.redeSocial {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #2f3036;
}

/* Estilo para os links dos botões */
.redeSocial a {
    display:block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Cor para cada botão */
.facebookShare {background-color:#3E5A97;}
.twitterShare {background-color:#2EA7DE;}
.pinterestShare {background-color:#C3292D;}
.whatsAppShare {background-color:#5BBE4A;}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .whatsApp {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Podes ler mais sobre o `table-layout: fixed;` aqui neste link: [CSS table-layout Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Comment: É isto mesmo, muito obrigado ajudou bastante

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você precisa atualizar a largura dos outros três botões, pois dependendo da largura que estava definida, eles não vão atualizar mesmo.
Por exemplo, você pode deixar a width:25% na versão mobile e 33% na versão desktop.

Comment: Olá Joel, então a questão é, as outras LI não se ajustam por que a ultima LI que é a do whatsapp está lá ela só está oculta, ae as outras não se ajustam, eu precisaria sumir com a ultima LI na versão mobile e não simplesmente ocultar ela.

Comment: Mas é isso @MarcosMamede , você deve atualizar o width das mesmas após ocultar a ultima LI, mesmo que chegue a usar o JavaScript para excluir a LI, não adiantaria nada.

Answer (score 1):

As outras `<li>` não se ajustam por que a última `<li>` que é a do whatsapp está lá, ela só está oculta, ai as outras não se ajustam, eu precisaria sumir com a última `<li>` na versão mobile e não simplesmente ocultar ela.