# Alinhamento de tabela

Tags: html, css

Porque é que os dados das páginas das rodadas  [desta tabela](http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000369-c7177c90b2/Rodadas%20-%20C%C3%B3pia.html) não estão alinhados de forma correta?

Gostaria que eles ficassem de forma correta, ou seja alinhados como o resto das outras rodadas, tipo`2,4,7,9` sem ter a sensação de espaçamento do lado esquerdo, pois todas as vezes que passo para outra rodada os dados ficam desalinhados.

Comment: Notei que tem vários `id` repetidos, mude-os `id` nunca podem ser iguais.

Comment: Mudei os ID's como orientado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é porque não está a ser aplicada nenhuma largura para as `td`.
Há dias respondi uma [pergunta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76118/11886) com esta. Podes usar este mesmo hack para resolver este problema. Isto vai calcular e ajustar a largura das `td` de maneira a que fiquem todas iguais com a mesma largura:

```
tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px 0px;
}
td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Aqui tens também um exemplo online no jsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/vj6q6bkz**

Ou em vez de aplicares os estilos apontando para as `tr` e `td` poderias criar uma class especial para isto, e assim sempre que precisares de aplicar este "hack" ao que quer que seja, basta adicionares a class no Markup (HTML). Por exemplo:

```
.tabelaAutoAlinhada {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px 0px;
}
.celulaAutoAlinhada {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Podes ler mais sobre isto em: [Lista Horizontal Responsiva](http://truquesedicascss.blogspot.pt/2015/07/lista-horizontal-responsiva-100-por-cento-largura-width.html#hack-lista-horizontal)
Também reparei que tens vários estilos inline iguais para cada `td` e `tr` que se encontram no HTML

```
<td height="23" style="height: 23px; text-align: center;">Pó_de_arroz</td>
```

Em vez de fazeres isto como já disse a pouco mais acima, podes criar uma class e adicionar este estilos numa só vez de estares a escrever o mesmo estilo consecutivamente para cada uma delas, reduzindo o tamanho do teu documento HTML:

```
<td class="minhaTD">Pó_de_arroz</td>
```

E a class gerada no CSS irá ser:

```
.minhaTD {height: 23px; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: :d Perfeito... Deu certo aqui.

Comment: A questão das td's melhor ainda, fiz em uma aqui e perfeito, vou fazer nas demais... Boa.